# How can I perform a Git Status that doesn't check remotes?

Tags: git

I am juggling different VPNs due to my company's rather fragmented set-up. Is there a way to run a Git Status command WITHOUT checking status against the remotes? I.e. just check local changes? Or an equivalent command? It's a PITA not to be able to just do a Git Status without switching VPNs just to do that.

Comment: why would switching vpn effect git status command(git status is comparing localy)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git status` should check your local branches (e.g. `refs/master`) vs your locally fetched cloned remote branches (e.g. `refs/origin/master`).

There should be no network traffic when simply issuing `git status`. Of course without a `git fetch` first, you won't really be comparing to the up-to-date state of the remote.

Comment: Thank you. It was taking a long time and I assumed (because anything else connecting to those servers just timed out like this) that it was failing to connect to the remotes. In fact, it was just the (incredibly crappy) performance of my shared folder on my VM. Doh!

Comment: @JaneDoe: if you're using VirtualBox (or Vagrant which uses VirtualBox), I ended up resorting to the rule: "shared folders only when absolutely required, which for Git is never". :-) Those shared directories are bizarrely slow in unpredictable ways.

Comment: @torek Thanks. They really are. I've actually moved away from them now for an unrelated reason: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51561997/can-create-and-delete-files-on-mounted-file-system-yet-not-create-links-or-chang